# What's the advantage of UTF-8 over highest-bit encoding such as ULEB128 or LLVM bitcode?

Tags: string, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii

Highest-bit encoding means

> if a byte starts with 0 it's the final byte, if a byte starts with 1 it's not the final byte

notice, this is also ASCII compatible, in fact, this is what LLVM bitcode does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key property that UTF-8 has which ULEB128 lacks, is that no UTF-8 character encoding is a substring of any other UTF-8 character. Why does this matter? It allows UTF-8 to satisfy an absolutely crucial design criterion: you can apply C string functions that work on single-byte encodings like ASCII and Latin-1 to UTF-8 and they will work correctly. This is not the case for ULEB128, as we'll see. That in turn means that most programs written to work with ASCII or Latin-1 will also "just work" when passed UTF-8 data, which was a huge benefit for the adoption of UTF-8 on older systems.

First, here's a brief primer on how ULEB128 encoding works: each code point is encoded as a sequence of bytes terminated by a byte without the high bit set—we'll call that a "low byte" (values 0-127); each leading byte has the high bit set—we'll call that a "high byte" (values 128-255). Since ASCII characters are 0-127, they are all low bytes and thus are encoded the same way in ULEB128 (and Latin-1 and UTF-8) as in ASCII: i.e. any ASCII string is also a valid ULEB128 string (and Latin-1 and UTF-8), encoding the same sequence of code points.

Note the subcharacter property: any ULEB128 character encoding can be prefixed with any of the 127 high byte values to encode longer, higher code points. This cannot occur with UTF-8 because the lead byte encodes how many following bytes there are, so no UTF-8 character can be contained in any other.

Why does this property matter? One particularly bad case of this is that the ULEB128 encoding of any character whose code point is divisible by 128 will contain a trailing NUL byte (`0x00`). For example, the character `Ā` (capital "A" with bar over it) has code point U+0100 which would be encoded in ULEB128 as the bytes `0x82` and `0x00`. Since many C string functions interpret the NUL byte as a string terminator, they would incorrectly interpret the second byte to be the end of the string and interpret the `0x82` byte as an invalid dangling high byte. In UTF-8 on the other hand, a NUL byte only ever occurs in the encoding of the NUL byte code point, U+00, so this issue cannot occur.

Similarly, if you use `strchr(str, c)` to search a ULEB128-encoded string for an ASCII character, you can get false positives. Here's an example. Suppose you have the following very Unicode file path: `/☯`. This is presumably a file in your collection of burrito recipes for the burrito you call "The Yin & Yang". This path name has the following sequence of code points:

- — Unicode U+1F32F
- `/` — ASCII/Unicode U+2F
- `☯` — Unicode U+262F

In ULEB128 this would be encoded with the following sequence of bytes:

- `10000111` – leading byte of  (U+1F32F)
- `11100110` – leading byte of  (U+1F32F)
- `00101111` – final byte of  (U+1F32F)
- `00101111` – only byte of `/` (U+2F)
- `11001100` – leading byte of `☯` (U+262F)
- `00101111` – final byte of `☯` (U+262F)

If you use `strchr(path, '/')` to search for slashes to split this path into path components, you'll get bogus matches for the last byte in  and the last byte in `☯`, so to the C code it would look like this path consists of an invalid directory name `\x87\xE6` followed by two slashes, followed by another invalid directory name `\xCC` and a final trailing slash. Compare this with how this path is encoded in UTF-8:

- `11110000` — leading byte of  (U+1F32F)
- `10011111` — continuation byte of  (U+1F32F)
- `10001100` — continuation byte of  (U+1F32F)
- `10101111` — continuation byte of  (U+1F32F)
- `00101111` — only byte of `/` (U+2F)
- `11110000` — leading byte of `☯` (U+262F)
- `10011111` — continuation byte of `☯` (U+262F)
- `10010000` — continuation byte of `☯` (U+262F)
- `10101111` — continuation byte of `☯` (U+262F)

The encoding of `/` is `0x2F` which doesn't—and cannot—occur anywhere else in the string since the character does not occur anywhere else—the last bytes of  and `☯` are `0xAF` rather than `0x2F`. So using `strchr` to search for `/` in the UTF-8 encoding of the path is guaranteed to find the slash and only the slash.

The situation is similar with using `strstr(haystack, needle)` to search for substrings: using ULEB128 this would find actual occurrences of `needle`, but it would also find occurrences of `needle` where the first character is replaced by any character whose encoding extends the actual first character. Using UTF-8, on the other hand, there cannot be false positives—every place where the encoding of `needle` occurs in `haystack` it can only encode `needle` and cannot be a fragment of the encoding of some other string.

There are other pleasant properties that UTF-8 has—many as a corollary of the subcharacter property—but I believe this is the really crucial one. A few of these other properties:

- You can predict how many bytes you need to read in order to decode a UTF-8 character by looking at its first byte. With ULEB128, you don't know you're done reading a character until you've read the last byte.
- If you embed a valid UTF-8 string in any data, valid or invalid, it cannot affect the interpretation of the valid substring. This is a generalization of property that no character is a subsequence of any other character.
- If you start reading a UTF-8 stream in the middle and you can't look backwards, you can tell if you're at the start of a character or in the middle of one. With ULEB128, you might decode the tail end of a character as a different character that looks valid but is incorrect, whereas with UTF-8 you know to skip ahead to the start of a whole character.
- If you start reading a UTF-8 stream in the middle and you want to skip backwards to the start of the current character, you can do so without reading past the start of the character. With ULEB128 you'd have read one byte before the start of a character (if possible) to know where the character starts.
- To address the previous two points you could use a little-endian variant of ULEB128 where you encode the bits of each code point in groups of seven from least to most significant. Then the first byte of each character's encoding is a low byte and the trailing bytes are high bytes. However, this encoding sacrifices another pleasant property of UTF-8, which is that if you sort an encoded strings lexicographically by bytes, they are sorted into the same order as if you had sorted them lexicographically by characters.

An interesting question is whether UTF-8 is inevitable given this set of pleasant properties? I suspect that some variation is possible, but not very much.

- You want to anchor either the start or end of the character with some marker that cannot occur anywhere else. In UTF-8 this is a byte with 0, 2, 3 or 4 leading ones, which indicates the start of a character.
- You want to encode the length of a character somehow, not just an indicator of when a character is done, since this prevents extending one valid character to another one. In UTF-8 the number of leading bits in the leading byte indicates how many bytes are in the character.
- You want the start/end marker and the length encoding at the beginning so that you know in the middle of a stream that if you're at the start of a character or not and so that you know how many bytes you need to complete the character.

There are probably some variations that can satisfy all of this and the lexicographical ordering property, but with all these constraints UTF-8 starts to seem pretty inevitable.

Answer (score 2):

If you drop a byte in a stream, or jump into the middle of a stream, UTF-8 can synchronize itself without ambiguity. If all you have is a single "last/not-last" flag, then you can't detect that a byte has been lost, and will silently decode the sequence incorrectly. In UTF-8, this can be converted to REPLACEMENT CHARACTER (U+FFFD) to indicate a non-decodable section, or the entire character will be lost. But it's much rarer to get the *wrong* character due to dropped bytes.

It also provides a clear memory limit on decoding. From the first byte, you immediately know how many bytes you need to read to complete the decode. This is important for security, since the scheme you describe could be used to exhaust memory unless you include an arbitrary limit on the length of a sequence. (This problem *does* exist for Unicode combining characters, and there's a special [Stream-Safe Text Format](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Stream_Safe_Text_Format) that imposes just such arbitrary limits, but this only impacts parsers that require normalization.) This also can help performance, since you know immediately how many bytes to load to decode the entire code point.

You also know how many bytes you can safely skip in a searching operation. If the first byte is a mismatch, you can jump to the next character in a single step without reading the intermediate bytes.

It is also fairly unambiguous with other encodings since it's sparse. A random sequence of bytes, and particularly an extended ASCII encoding, is almost certainly not valid UTF-8. There are a few values that can *never* occur, so if found, you can rule out UTF-8 entirely, and there are rules for the values that can occur. The scheme you're describing is dense. Every sequence is legal, just like extended ASCII. That makes it harder to accurately detect the encoding.

Answer (score 2):

There are trade off in most encodings.

Note: you are proposing something between encoding and escaping, which makes some things difficult to compare.

UTF-8 gained popularity because: it is quick to decode, it is full compatible with ASCII, and it is self-synchronizing, and you can decode BMP (so codepoint until 0xFFFF) with 3 bytes (so not much overhead).

Your encoding is also self-synchronizing: 0 on high bit indicate end of a code point. Quick: yes, it is just shift operation (and compare + masking high bits), and efficient: you encode characters until 0x7FFF with just two bytes (UTF-8 until 0x07FF). And such encodings were not unknown when UTF-8 where developed.

But the problem it is that you are using an "escaping" model. Byte 0x41 (ASCII letter A) can be read as letter A, or as final character of a sequence (so not a letter A). Which may be a security problem, when just comparing strings. It is easy to correct the code (you should just check backward only one single character). Note: also UTF-8 has some security issues: overlong sequence (which are illegal) may skip simple string comparison.

Note: I do not think having an over long sequence is a problem. UTF-8 has also a limit (which were lowered compared first version), and in practical use, we convert to an integer, so it has limited size (and so it should not spill other other bytes). OTOH like UTF-8, one should check the size and reject invalid sequences/codepoints (e.g. above 0x10FFFF).

So, I do not know the exact reason, and UTF-8 "sucks" also because it is not compatible with ISO-10646 (so C1 control code with just one bytes). OTOH UTF-1 design is also bad (and so now it is an obsolete encoding).

I have my suspect such encoding were ruled out because of "escaping" problem: easy to fix, but not interoperable (in a secure way) with old programs. UTF-8-unaware programs just works without surprises (but ev. with error not knowing the meaning of high bit characters). [Note: your proposal and UTF-8 both fails ISO-10646 (but it allows UTF-8 with special consideration: disregard bytes 0x80-0x9F (C1 bytes), so terminals may need to be UTF-8 aware.].

I think efficiency were not so high in stack: CJK characters with ISO-10646 were coded with longer sequences then UTF-8, and getting rid of most ISO-10646 encoding handling would simplify most programs. [ISO-10646 has also additional (non-encoding) functionalities].